# dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: wrong dismissing animation. iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiviewcontroller

When i call

`[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:TRUE completion:^{
}];`

ViewController appears from bottom like presenting animation, instead of default dismissing.
And ViewController stays on screen when completion block executing. Just after completion block was executed ViewController disappears without animation.

Comment: Are you calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated:` from a background thread?

Comment: I thought about it. I tried insert my code to dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{}), but unsuccessfully :(